# Unable to display legend for a quantile scale in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display a legend for a heat map I have created, but am unable to do that. Here is my HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Heat Map Data Visualization</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='chart-area'>
      <svg class='chart'></svg>
      <svg class='legend'></svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the legend I am trying to create

```
var legend = d3.select('.legend')
                 .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d){
                   return d;
                 });

  legend.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend-element');

  legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          console.log(i);
          return legendElementWidth * i + (width - legendElementWidth * buckets);
        })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", gridHeight / 2)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) {
          return colors[i];
        });
```

When I use Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the element, I see that the required g elements have been created but they all have dimensions of 0x0.

I read somewhere that rect elements can only be appended to an svg element, which is why I changed my HTML code to include an svg element with a class of legend, however I am still not getting any result.

Here is a link to the codepen for this program

http://codepen.io/redixhumayun/pen/eBqamb?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your pen like [this](http://codepen.io/mkaranasou/pen/NdWpzr):

```
// Save the legend svg in a variable   
// also changed the translate in order to keep the legend within the svg         
// and place it on the right side just for the example's sake
    var legendSvg = svg.append('g')
         .attr('class', 'legend')
        .attr("transform","translate("+ (width - 40) + ",20)")

// Define the legend as you did
var legend = d3.legendColor()
                 .useClass(true)
                 .shape('rect')
                 .orient('vertical')
                 .title('Temperature Variance')
                 .shapeWidth(legendElementWidth)
                 .scale(colorScale);

// And then call legend on the legendSvg not on svg itself
 legendSvg.call(legend);
```

Hope this helps, good luck!