# D3: Why doesn't the heatmap color legend appear?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**SITUATION:**

[image]

**QUESTION:**

I am trying to create a heatmap graph with D3.js which I managed. I now have trouble making the legend appear.

Why doesn't the legend appear ?

The legend should appear like here for example: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/aNLYPp

**CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    // Excellent example from Tom May helped me when I got stuck: http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json", function(error, json) {
      if (error) {
          return console.warn(error);
      }
      visualizeThe(json);
    });

    function visualizeThe(data) {

        const baseTemperature = data.baseTemperature;
        const tempData = data.monthlyVariance;

        const margin = {
            top: 10,
            right: 85,
            bottom: 65,
            left: 70
        }

        const w = 1250 - margin.left - margin.right;
        const h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        const barWidth = Math.ceil(w / tempData.length);
        const legendElementWidth = w/12;


        const colors = ["#5e4fa2", "#3288bd", "#66c2a5", "#abdda4", "#e6f598", "#ffffbf", "#fee08b", "#fdae61", "#f46d43", "#d53e4f", "#9e0142"];
        const buckets = colors.length;
        const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        const  minTime = d3.min(tempData, (d) => new Date(d.year,1,1,0,0));
        const  maxTime = d3.max(tempData, (d) => new Date(d.year,1,1,0,0));

        const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([minTime, maxTime]) 
            .range([margin.left, w]);   

        const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(20);

        const svg = d3.select("#results")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",  w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        const div = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")  
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h+margin.top) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        const monthsLabels = svg.selectAll("monthLabel")
            .data(months)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text((d) => d)
            .attr("x", 100)
            .attr("y", (d,i) => i * h/12 + 21)
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-40," +0+ ")")
            .style("font-size", 10);

        const colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
          .domain([d3.min(tempData, (d) => d.variance + baseTemperature ), d3.max(tempData, (d) => d.variance + baseTemperature )])
          .range(colors);

        const heatMap = svg.selectAll("month")
          .data(tempData, (d) => d);

        const rects = heatMap.enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", (d) => xScale(new Date(d.year,1,1,0,0)))
          .attr("y", (d) => d.month * h/12 - margin.bottom + margin.top -1)
          .attr("width", barWidth + 3)
          .attr("height", h/12 )
          .style("fill", colors[0])
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {        
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html( d.year +" "+ months[d.month-1]+"<br>"+(d.variance + baseTemperature).toFixed(3)+"    &deg;C  <br>"+d.variance+" Variance")   
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 50) + "px");    
            })                  
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
            });

      rects.transition().duration(1000)
          .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.variance + baseTemperature));

          svg.append("text")             
              .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + (w/2) + " ," + 
                    (h+ margin.top + 45) + ")")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text("Years");

          svg.append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", -5)
              .attr("x",0 - (h / 2))
              .attr("dy", "1em")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text("Months");   

       const legend = svg.selectAll("legend")
          .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), (d) => d);

       const legendEntries = legend.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend");

          legendEntries.append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d, i)  => (w*0.7)+ legendElementWidth/4 * i )
            .attr("y", h + 40)
            .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .style("fill", (d, i) => colors[i]);

          legendEntries.append("text")
            .data(tempData)
            .text((d) => "≥ " + Math.round(d.variance+baseTemperature))
            .attr("x", (d, i) =>(w*0.7)+ legendElementWidth/4 * i)
            .attr("y", h + 75);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? I am willing to modify my question if necessary but please explain.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your title could be a lot more specific.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439050/unable-to-display-legend-for-a-quantile-scale-in-d3/41445879#41445879

Comment: @MikeChamberlain Touché ! Hmmm, I'll see how I can make it more specific.

Comment: @mkaran No errors in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is causing you problems:

```
   const legend = svg.selectAll("legend")
      .data(tempData.concat(colorScale.quantiles()), (d) => d["month"] );

      legend.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend");

      legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d,i)  => legendElementWidth * i)
        .attr("y", h)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", 5)
        .style("fill", (d, i) => colors[i]);

      legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text((d) => "≥ " + Math.round(d.variance+baseTemperature))
        .attr("x", (d, i) =>legendElementWidth * i)
        .attr("y", h + 4);
```

Note that  your enter selection is used only for appending 'g' elements. You need to append rectangles and text using the enter selection too. Contrast your code with:

```
   const legend = svg.selectAll("legend")
      .data(tempData.concat(colorScale.quantiles()), (d) => d["month"] );

   const legendEntries = legend.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend");

      legendEntries.append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d,i)  => legendElementWidth * i)
        .attr("y", h)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", 5)
        .style("fill", (d, i) => colors[i]);

      legendEntries.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text((d) => "≥ " + Math.round(d.variance+baseTemperature))
        .attr("x", (d, i) =>legendElementWidth * i)
        .attr("y", h + 4);
```

The enter selection returns elements that need to be added to the DOM. Here, we append a 'g', with its datum, for each element that needs to added. Then we append items to the 'g's we just entered.

It is not part of your question, but you might want to examine the data you are passing to your legend.